# store arbitrary JavaScript code into a string variable

Tags: javascript, java, clojure, nashorn

I have a program (written in Clojure)  that injects some JS code into a JS function, then evaluates it via Nashorn. I have no control over the code passes (it may contain quotes, simple quotes...).

It looks like this :

```
;; Clojure
(eval-str (str "print(evaluateCode(\"" s  " \"))"))

// equivalent code in pseudo-js just for those not reading Clojure fluently
evalJS("println(evaluateCode(" + arbitraryJS + "))")
```

The `evaluateCode` function is already loaded.

```
// already loaded in Nashorn
function evaluateCode(code) {
   // do something with the code
   //...
   eval(code);
}
```

This works fine for simple programs, ex. if `arbitraryJS = "var a=123; print(a); return a;"`.

But as soon as the program contains quotes, it breaks. ex. `"var a = 123; print("a is now", a);"`

**Note :** the actual code is [there](https://github.com/nha/boot-uglify/blob/66fb4633ab98b42e81cf29c24d43569fd8631924/src/nha/boot_uglify.clj#L133).

Comment: What about escaping the quotes like \" ?

Comment: use the other quotes? `'` because I think you create new string literals this way

Comment: @Berger I think there could be corner cases (template strings come to mind, comments maybe) ?

Comment: @Thomas well I should have put emphasis on **arbitrary** code, which may contain simple quotes as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the after end I used the [Apache Commons Lang StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) since the other solutions did not work. See it [here](https://github.com/nha/boot-uglify/blob/81cb16a2236c562dd35bae664cc614f51211a68b/src/nha/boot_uglify/impl.clj#L107).

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the string. place a \ before every ".
If you need the \ itself use it double \\

Sorry, I am not allowed to comment yet... :/

Comment: I replied to @Berger the same, but how would you address corner cases (if any) ? I am thinking comments, template strings but there may be others.

Comment: comments use regular slashes and should not be a problem. For a line break escape with \n: Template strings seem to work aswell. Yust try it: 

`var n = "var x = 0; //sets the var \n console.log(x); var b = \`Hi\n${2+13}!\`; console.log(b) /* dose stuff*/" ;`

Comment: For the comments, I was thinking something more like : `var a="abc", b='ABC; /* "a" and 'b' are both variables */ \n'`. 
Or maybe ```var a="abc", b='ABC; `This is a template string. Can I contain "quotes", and should they be quoted again?` ```.

Comment: I see; Where dose the arbitrarry code come from? if its stored as string it should work as expected. If it's generated the same rules apply. escape using backslashes.

`var s = "var a=\"abc\", b='ABC; \`This is a template string. Can I contain \"quotes\", and should they be quoted again?\`";`

Comment: The arbitrary code comes from a build tool. So you are saying that I should escape code in template strings ? I was under the impression that I should left them as-is instead.

Comment: leave it as it is. only if you are building it your self you need to escape it.

Comment: Right, now it becomes a bit less straightforward though (ex. nested quotes/template quotes/comments).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to escape the quotes and backslashes. I would go for single quotes as JS string delimiters, as in Clojure you are bound to use double quotes for delimiting strings:

```
;; Clojure
(eval-str (str "print(evaluateCode('"
               (clojure.string/replace s #"(['\\\\])" "\\\\$1")
               "'))"))
```

The find and replace patterns each have four backslashes. As in Clojure backslash is an escape character, they actually denote only two backslashes. In regular expressions backslash is *also* an escape character, so in the end they just denote one, literal backslash each. So this means *"prefix any occurrence of backslash or quote with a backslash."*

You shouldn't worry about comments and templates and such, as the escape characters only exist in Clojure (after the replace), but are resolved the moment the complete string is parsed by the Javascript engine. The *evaluateCode* function will never see the escape characters, but the plain value of *s*.

**Example**

```
;; Clojure
(def s "a = 'test'; // 'test' used here")
(eval-str (str "print(evaluateCode('"
               (clojure.string/replace s #"(['\\\\])" "\\\\$1")
               "'))"))
```

This will evaluate to:

```
(eval-str "print(evaluateCode('a = \\'test\\'; // \\'test\\' used here'))")
```

Note that the backslashes are doubled in the above representation, but that is because Clojure needs that. The actual string only has single occurrences of the backslashes. If instead of calling `eval-str`, you would call `println` with the same argument, you would get this output:

> print(evaluateCode('a = \'test\'; // \'test\' used here'))

That is the string interpreted by the Javascript engine, and so it interprets the backslashes as escape characters, passing the clean string to *evaluateCode*.

So if *evaluateCode* looked like this:

```
function evaluateCode(code) {
   alert(code);
}
```

It would produce this alert:

> a = 'test'; // 'test' used here

So, the escaping backslashes are not there at all in Javascript. It will see the exact same value as the Clojure symbol *s* represents.